# Multipart/formdata files parsing

Tags: javascript, node.js, request, multipartform-data

I'm trying to parse a multipart/formdata request manually on NodeJS.

Everything in the request is parsed correctly except for files. I'm reading the file data, but its length is shorter than the original's (in fiddler, selecting the bytes in hexView: 25,830 bytes, read from the request 24,840 bytes)

I'm splitting the request body to parts by boundaries, then each part is split by `\r\n\r\n` to separate headers and value.

Here's the request:

```
------WebKitFormBoundaryLgBrFdAMLHRuYHlS
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file-source"; filename="reg_form_user.PNG"
Content-Type: image/png

�PNG

���
IHDR�����K���Z����sRGB�������gAMA����
�a���   pHYs�������o�d��c�IDATx^���sy]��`~q�:�s8�Κի�k9S.��0����$�,/�zР�1��e���7̈-l
�b�(�F1r�4�BZ�NCC����߾���K���|>��|���U�z�����g�g՛���;;��<{�7�r��������p(o���.w��������+�������b������+������b������+������b������+������b������+������b������+������b������+������b������+������b��p"|�߈�'  ���lB��E��c�I�ݖ7��Mx��v��
�pZ�;w.��Ǌ�}�cR�VOU[��>v���o}kt
N
uΨ�iA��&D:�\4v�N�/��&D�jB��ECD�.l_�8M��ՄH����<]ؾ�p��    ��
y��}6���z��_.o|�������_����/��/�����H���2�̱"��_�j�����X�RD�ۿ��\�pA�����/��?���ߧ��Y����}h�=��~��׾��2�L�)��Hw����������?���BN�cE:���/"��]r�ܜ[[[�җ�T>���FS���r9x�_���������wO"`���׾�|���_��_����a��\O;���׽N����xz�N����EsP�_u�Ur�]wɣ�>�/��/r��J�T��z(�r���G><�������O��<����wN"`��ů�M�3ԟ����馛��������n���;�����,��G�G
?[����7޸�Zox���5�
{�
{y�'���z��o�ϰ��5�YX�?��?��j���1���ĿU����t��xE��n�!�YlCn��n��7m޶{���/y���/���|�w�w��'{���k�Ҵ�}1���<c��������믟[�x"�.��"�X,���3��n)
��˳�����o�>D:�fw��:q��_������ J���������o�t� �z=���_���0�g��������������9n�'Ϥ�o�߿�[���>������D���u���ӂ��mˍc5�{��-�����oh��_�U����
6/�c�{�w��~�?�Vvdڿ�}���k�����^�
m[���կ~u���Fz�9�z�gn���1�m#"�N��F�ݶ����@��o�y���}7�I��k���A��?��?.��M����
=�7 ��^;�����g�����˿�[��Ϊ|۷}[�C?^'�.��^>���
����e�Y�n���v�"`��u�
�s^��)��������O|"���w�s�s������͞�)���IFc��F�ac�����s:����_��`ݒ�sI��=�?��?   �?���h������
�1���<m���İ�-�����x �x[�{��W�*�����Dz�s2���o����="�N��9����}N����o*���>�ai����>������A�7�g?���?����ئ��yZ�ۯz���_���H������o�'��m}P�'�Y�l�Ag�
"`��;*�6D���' ����Ͼ/1��������x� 4��F2m��D�k��]l>v�Ţ7~>v&ۢ��\���n6?
f;�o�Ʊj�H��������r�U�����d��p��ˌI��G��M������}���a�{�S�"w�yg������-oyK����������`��n˵���/�B0��p���}��g~�g���6Ͳ�g�:�n���E�Q����Aܹg��~�����O����K�~�ag���a���m:��]��|�~Kj�M.��
Z�-�
�����s�y��w�i}��˱a1��m}�`$~��da��ǘ=�Ŏ6♝��#�X=��8DcӮ�bo��E�3��Ly�G�l���=��bg����O2�{�#���&?���-��R�z��sH�t�4G�Πv� �6
��8`]�b����N�0;�n�cl�eΤ�P��H.�$"=�.i�+ƚς�����q���Yæ�cՖg��m����������s7��;J��;Id?�チ�x�cE:���A�nQkq{�����
��~PZ���_�H�ψ�a?X-�����{��w�#�N��v�����_3�"�7�Q�3臝E7�t���b.-~�3��o㳭6��~�؉�����}��3�6v=>o�iC
m�L�7��|����.�D�_��_�}�u�6mL�=/���n��{Bl]����O���L�����ۖiu��2��='ÞC<�)��N�p��h.6�
;�aqn?����?�8��`�ƔĦ]�L�
��q�/y�K�1�8�m|�����"��iN"`��;��n�vV�=�m?�l8D|&�~~ٰ�����H|Ww��Ϣۉ�xY�6�
������$���&����WN�e��}�?��?
~.Zp�v�F�g�����{u�t��/��]\l]}�n���V��m���r,�m=��Mo7vf=����x{���������<'�Ʃ��}���pќD������j����P���1��Cq_>�Ϥ�I�7'� �]:˰H��%�nc���ň�W~�W��qp�E�AӜD:�f��Q6���~����N^����c�.��gAhgc-m�u��3��e�Z^�t�]{������y/���c�Ak�s��n?���$y�����v�����-^G�G�mS{���`�����Y��c}�r�yN�o<�ߌD:��('������l�{��~P�Ww�?|z��]�r�6&>#�F�a�o߷��_��צnc�ݳJi�~�4����!�Ŵ�r���D��x?)����W"�.���t��:�_���%y�t;��^�,y���<�9�������t��ޜ.��૝���W|1�"��iN"���>�H?A�t���"҆��Wu�D:��&D�ų2�n�k���4u����jsi�]���.@���B��&Ǌt�����H�b��+���J�D:��كH���b"��E�UV���>�!D:��كH��¢:��$�d����
��قH��������3�x���mo��3���p6 ��D�L���v�8�������+������b������+������b������+������b������+������b������+������b������+������b������+�\��ߐX������4�E�ݸ�{��^DDDDD��E�'?�I��;����|���"""""��j
~�wʧ?�i����#���ԧ>%w�uW��FDDDD���3��L��w��h4Z�t�����6���ߏ�������< >��<��C��#�,w����g?Lt���`"DDDDD<=}�Qy���
2��#}0g����?Lh=��㈈���x�>�����~>�m��
y�S�V�q�ۄ�����x�~�
_��t�d��I�#=�/~�����
��I'���HGDDDD\1�tDDDD��HGDDDD\1�tDDDD��HGDDDD\1�tDDDD��HGDDDD\1��c�5(DDDD<ܴ�B�D���h�mDDDD<ش�2Ӻ
C��L�H���O """��E{Z��u�t��N�s�&I?���!"""b´n�{Z��e���@Oƹ�p��8�
��=�""""&�[)n'7��X'�%�&ݍ�}���o�)��_��������:�z*���D�cZ��g���L���hZW�g�  �E�tǴ@�_��v睩;""""O�+무PO봳&����nGx6��������|����O�s�� ��&�/Ynx��M����:�z+�:�>5�!�g�m;�cГo���')�����z�T�W�Y���=�N��鑶3�g�m�y��G����ӝ�HG�ӖH�M��*�,�-��Gz|6=��ΒDzd����h�~�b�`4��L�7TDē�H�M��*�,�-��l:�J���#���E�����ۙ��TOJ"�6������ܱ�q���P'��xG����Nuy��v��7UDē�H�M��*�xȋ�R"�H�����;ݞ�C=l
wgJ��""��D:�l:nWYgYoYw���8���i�vV$�U_��8���ongr�LOZ"�6�����q��3�H�I��n����QD:"f-�����Uq���ҭÈ�P"]�E�}�᳟���Δ����xR����]e��~x�H�I��D:"��D:�l:nW�~�t�HG�U�H�M��*"�/��鈸*����]E��%�U"WE"�6���t�D�J�#�H����v��HW�tD\�t��tܮ"���*����"�����UD�_"]%�qU$��T�7dwwW��6�%��*"�/����w 7=+'��o=���'�~�����Hnޭ¾���DӜD:��nW�~�t�HG�D:f+�~�#�*��XƁC�5�R��e�=���ܮ"���*��~�t�V"��FzMz�퐉t+z�%d:lnW�~�t�HG�G���zõr��M�2��/��n{���:�Un��Jy��Z�IWʵ7�*���o�����-�W]s�\��Nn:�ō�H?{�G��_��w�2n��U�۵��F���cǽ������䷋Ri9�fz����l��5�ZR)ƏٓzoM3�A�"��N���bEZ���8.W��ؖ�~?�U��zO�K����UD�_"]%����"��7\)�o�Nnz�@�������=KnD�yP#�ʜ\v͍���Pn��Ur�e9���F�#=��x�In��V�=�7�
��GZ��M����}�H�ץ�ۑr�/��H���I���O�t�o�,��P�Þ4��o_�NA[{��vt��@�U�&_�N<�a�w���I�֕�x,�^C�_NvtEN|�=�<nW�~�t�HG�G��i|��t�
�����o|���]'�<�#������v�O}�m���ْH?{�}p�,��Ι��"}���D����5��N��]i��ư%%����+U
�]w��8[nI�f7F݆���7p�p��H�K��D:�=J�?(��J
�g����&'�禿�&�]�����[*���m#�Y7
�ų"�~�X���XF��T
yٝ�i^.�'�Z��b�#�Q�9��H��g�Sj:����m�ug�7��ϡ���3�rSz�q���v��HW�t�{�H7�r����5�_�>��ɫn�O��/J�c(�~��I�8���x9t
��^<��(�3��ؑ��J�ρ�5F]i���e��o�^�-�a�pFp��H�K��D:��º�l�;>x����k��eRy�
w9h^�D�Y�H?{x#};    ;x�H�1����W�ΰ��D�N������1   ��Z��S�?
g   ���t�D�J��A���o�ܷ_/�&��o�kݠ�"/~�S��[ݫ��G�w^S��.�~�8�L��ԃ?<4�����Go���<v,�ʮ3D&$�|)��D�}�ӽ�����7���ߚ
�0`�q��H�K��D:����
,�=�z�嶁���m�Q��R߀��^�;
��|�ez_tu�a|&�J�>����!/���\w��z�0��;n|�<��[��`D�Y�H?{��>?&}�kJ9q�y��7j��J{ ��@�Ͳ��품���ë��WY�]E�P;胣�D�2l%�/J��˶���R/�OϮ��٘���.���������)ܮ"���*���:�Mnz��k�_�T���w� 9݃����_#�k��tO��Z�a:&=ҽN��Z��4D�Y�H?{���Ю#�0f{,���lk��r[R�t�����g�'2h�d/��y4�z�ǌ�`������:�}�r���{9���I/VZ�I?��]E��%�U"WE"�6���t�D�J�#�H����v��HW�tD\�t��tܮ"���*����"�����UD�_"]%�qU$�`�q��H�K��D:"��D:�l:nW�~�t�HG�U�H�M��*"�/��鈸*����]E��%�U"WE"�6���t�D�J�#�H����v��HW�tD\�t��tܮ"���*����"�����UD�_"]%�qU$�`�q��H�K��D:"��D:�l:nW�~�t�HG�U�H�M��*"�/��鈸*����]E��%�U"WE"�6���t�D�J�#�H����v��HW�����������*"�/��%�������]E��%�U"��� ܮ"���*�����
nW�~�t�H�������t�D�J����d��UD�_"]%�������*"�/���������v��HW�t����lp��H�K��D:���@6�]E��%�U"��� ܮ"���*�����
nW�~�t�H�������t�D�J����d��UD�_"]%�������*"�/���������v��HW�t����lp��H�K��D:���@6�]E��%�U"��� ܮ"���*�����
nW�~�t�H�������t�D�J����d��UD�_"]%�������*"�/���������v��HW�+���k�����\.'����׻2��{�����Hw�������*"�/���O�����q^(K�7��x,�^Sʅ���Z2��:��^�^tր�P:z�Y*l����l��K�����`q��H�K����nU�4�5>�0��~{�q�6KR,7��-{���i��R��m�LMٷ�5�2�~�1
�S/�V�*]^B�����*"�/���K��:��mH?�=c"�JNr����cpF��J&t�9���J)��?S=��e?:
���0n
t�f�j���rG��t>ΐˈ�9Kv����*z~[�j��oƃ���e)nE���45�)�K¸/M=H�
^�-=�jJ?�R�ڲ�U�z�?6iҫIA�����e��X���0��¾�{��{R�/�����Xi��Y�`?-5�����)ւ��ɠ%������^]����nW�~�tu]"� �N�D�^팃a1f���q�H�v��7���L��悔[}�G2hW����ךe�a�.��:6e/3��qG����m�l�OC��v��u����K>���ƽ?��t�K=�Ր�p,�A[�z;Wl:���u9/��~2�~cO��5
������-�N?d�̼��
:�=i�Ć��e�~[�&]���UnI_��x��0��`����x��Rܵ�ތd�o��r�m}������UD�_"]]�H�I���-����X�E�;e.�-�vr���AcW��:��桑��[�I�.�B��aS���#8P)��=w
��~I�d�$�At[���\�$���6���#��F��v��ە�3mp X�~�̼����_�6���l���w$��˟ߑeW8��p�����>�#u��[��0͕��U����v��HW��L�$>��<ÝI��g��'��'\����v��t5�Ә��D�?
s���͇KL����,�-�s�G:��ډn���'�^ ��ww�k��#��ю��φ�%�}�����qܮ"����:Fz��Y� l2���$
��x-Hm� ���AE��1ų+��.�.=�NM�w��L����Υ�FpP�y��ľ����{�C�9}_O�O���nW�~�tu]"���Q߫1��m��~ؙ��,w�}��u�H��7�O�E\zƝrpPV�fà���.%:�o��*��h�O�6����E�>q��S��ϙt�����*"�/���K��/�ؔ�F��̤�Ϟ��P8�H��I6�scҧL? :Y��kD�:�Սn�㈉�#x
��i�"�^�x�
�����E���c�P>|�)��I��ve��7uLz��*9&}~#�����UD�_"]]�H�j�^�1��@F���h,�n[j�Ř���u�w���L�[��g6��Ki�c�$z6�ݮ���I�בfeW��v��y��%|m
Rm�kՕv�$��k5
W{�燻�p���G}i�oI~��Iu��;;�\f�v)�f�.pu�fY�S��.�Ճ��
��p��]E��%����tc$���z�������3�+�l+s�b�pz��X.ҍî��F�|_�ˤ/����s��AY�1��X�ҩ��S�7��Ȏ��i  ^�J|��1�ۡ���1�v��^�|�y��S>+��NzQt�W_�:�D:��E�v��HW�+�6���\���,�v��HW�t���H�V�N��g���t�D�J�\
lX˖l����gC�&#tz���"��� ܮ"���*�p��Ȩېr)
��we�֑�al������*"�/���������v��HW�t����lp��H�K��D:���;w7�K��UD�_"]%�������*"�/���������v��HW�t����lp��H�K��D:���@6�]E��%�U"��� ܮ"���*�����
nW�~�t�H�������t�D�J����d��UD�_"]%�������*"�/���������v��HW�t����lp��H�K��D:���@6�]E��%�U"��� ܮ"���*�����
nW�~�t�H�������t�D�J����d��UD�_"]%�������*"�/���������v��HW�t����lp��H�K��D:���@6�]E��%�U"��� ܮ"���*�����
nW�~�t�H�������t�D�J����d��UD�_"]%�������*"�/���������v��HW�t����lp��H�K��D:���@6�]E��%�U"��� ܮ"���*�����
nW�~�t�H�������t�D�J����d��UD�_"]%�������*"�/���������v��HW�t����lp��H�K��D:���@6�]E��%�U"��� ܮ"����Dz���\� kҋ�][F-)�*ҝD���`�p��H�K����U��2N8h�6(�7�y���@*nW�~�tu�"==`G����d�
����"�AG�T:�h
����ܮ"�����F��/M
ݭ`(̖FpS�N�����ߪHq˦���^]z�.���_�ߖb�%��p�p�6�yK���}�A�xЕV����U��JSc�H���$ܮ"����fFz_ꅜ����e4hKUo�MFS�a]�x�i����m�B]1�J%oӴ�?��'�ך������H��2��^^���j=aX��2�Im7�t�R�������@o�ԔAt��)�v`�U���Ή�뻒׃��jW�s8ʴ�����]E��%�Ս��aK�wݘ�ޮ�4%��y�s���eG��}r�_ߑ܎��-�ACv�i���P;b�m��N3�q���-օq�����j�%���;�}������Oߩx��>g=ʴ�����]E��%���<��B�62�   �z�n��G�*�2�ɹ��Nr�>�۟���Q�o���am��,�s�܉�nG�RpA��c�_���;m��G���,�(�����v��HW75҇����nO�)�H�b*8S���e���y�Ez�f^��i%��0�}�)�F[�>R0�K�Q�f�=�=�~�!�fW���aG��F�3    G���V���t�D����nC�T;����Τ�g���8��Y
�]-p�����v��HW71҃i��㶾�
���>lJQ��s��`wL�D�]�^�9ù�p�hY
'���`cq��H�K������T[=���Ү�d;������^��#��NS�I?�o�`�AWw�ۮ�]l���I���Eܮ"����&F�hBw*E
s}L|m�^x�`$��s�S��|8N�����A�I��l�}�����n�˘t������UD�_"]]�H?i�����tq��H�K��D:���@6�]E��%�U"��� ܮ"���*�����
nW�~�t��F:���@ָ]E��%�U"��� ܮ"���*�p0�ΝCD�
�R�v��HW�t����lp��H�K��D:���@6�]E��%�U"��� ܮ"���*�����
nW�~�t�H�������t�D�J����d��UD�_"]%�������*"�/���������v��HW�t����lp��H�K��D:���@6�]E��%�U"��� ܮ"���*�����
nW�~�t�H�������t�D�J����d��UD�_"]%�������*"�/���������v��HW�t����lp��H�K��D:���@6�]E��%�U"��� ܮ"���*�����
nW�~�t�H�������t�D�J����d��UD�_"]%�������*"�/���������v��HW�t����lp��H�K��D:���@6�]E��%�U"��� ܮ"���*�����
nW�~�t�H�������t�D�J����d��UD�_"]%�������*"�/���������v��HW�t����lp��H�K��D:���@6�]E��%�U"��� ܮ"���*�����
nW�~�t�H�������t�D��.�ޫ�$��I/��2j��߃�ГZ.'��(�}���9�n�8���-iT�ew�-�[qؑ�~A�t;�r[R�oH}/b2hI��-y�&�-�JK��1��,��8���t�D�J��"�髴>~�m��-�cvؒ�|^v�m��2v�V�K�P�~4I8MN
�i��b���Cq��H�K��D:,�"�>�Ju{Oj���k�Rj��ת�^�1
�d���ٔ���w$�ېAt;�_��\^j�
��qB��Uu?��
��,��8���t�D����>H�R��=�~�_���+�^M�����8��/�{\I�:՝����J9����4���f�ޓ�Ȃ)�z�rR�9�fܓz<\a� ��y�ZRJ>�tC��u7�ҭE뽵|��W���P��m<���    ���K�Y���''[Ų4�����M��E�04,���u���ܺ�&��v�R����p��O�2'�d�����e�����v��HW73҇�,j\k�گ�{�س_��4q��#;;�g
�u)�u��HJ+�GU::�Ѡ-Ղ.�܉(��\� e���x(=�ς�P��R:FG����OS��i3M4vm9{M��2�5¡    �<��v��C�u�)�E���ԺC}|G�:��F_ƣ�����mq��]2��u�w~O=]�tY��3��Z����Z�GT+�Qbvҭ����G��v����3VuY��0��UD�_"]]�H?�Y��;e��<
ޑ�NW��$����e�IDt��%����6�0lv���"�:%�W��;.��    �9W����0�g�w�̨����us0����a'z`ps��T��������s+&��e�������@z����>j=X:f��B�/��d�-���>������ܮ"����zEzU:�f�As�Lz�17�NY��G��j��q-H�Cu���   �]����AӉ�(��R6�3����1������]ng���H?tݣ�W�G��I{O�m����R��F�qÎT*Ѳ�)����_q�F�[����߶��ؒ]}��&[�e�@nW�~�tu�"�9{��⋈���>�n�0�h;�%I�t��4�8�DzJ@������4��
�
�����^��a�7�G�2�\p7�>3��o;͘�4�p�������9�[�e�����t�D��ɑ�ԙt+
��VP��h�zZ�/����+i�H�h��!4
,�����n���yΤ7�����X�qG�6���q>�x������3��=��wu����N�0g4�(m۬Ҳ�����UD�_"]��HO3ݕ�arLz8M_ꅪt�mُ������yΑ��1���Oxy<}n)m3�Vt{�v����u�Ɓ��XP2��1���Hc�����l����x�p�8(f���
�Ѭ��M\y(8����c�UY����UD�_"]��H�����$"�b�T*y"ޘ]Ѥ3�x<�~�.����r<4� �V_F�:5)ڙ��%�O��rSz�\F�6+R��x��m��z%/%9?���}"�h(Dp����.�Y�t�+�̆-�}����~�ڒ^�'][����7:ң?T���8�e
7�oa��b����Ѡ��G�VbY��p(nW�~�tu3#]Y�:�N��R��
����3'[�}�w�    �3�-��]��3�>�:�S�Ŋ��d���۝�B�w�Ci��Ӯ���*J%���N��S�����y�su�گ3��4�_m���L?N�S���Ȭ²���pܮ"����D�������6���\nW�~�t�H?)�t���8���t�D�J��D:�����UD�_"]%�O
"�����*"�/���������v��HW�t����lp��H�K��D:���;w7�K��UD�_"]%�������*"�/���������v��HW�t����lp��H�K��D:���@6�]E��%�U"��� ܮ"���*�����
nW�~�t�H�������t�D�J����d��UD�_"]%�������*"�/���������v��HW�t����lp��H�K��D:���@6�]E��%�U"��� ܮ"���*�����
nW�~�t�H�������t�D�J����d��UD�_"]%�������*"�/���������v��HW�t����lp��H�K��D:���@6�]E��%�U"��� ܮ"���*�����
nW�~�t�H�������t�D�J����d��UD�_"]%�������*"�/���������v��HW�t����lp��H�K��D:���@6�]E��%�U"��� ܮ"���*�����
nW�~�t�H�������t�D�J����d��UD�_"]%�������*"�/���������v��HW�t����lp��H�K��D:���@6�]E��%�U"��� ܮ"���*�����
nW�~�t�H�������t�D�J����d��UD�_"]%�������*"�/���������v��HW�t����lp��H�K��D:���@6�]E��%�U"��� ܮ"���*�����
nW�~�t�HI��+����k��KcW׫яn��f$�RNr����N��ؗޟ�K�4w�QKJ���Z����`�p��H�K��D:��@J��벣q����p<��$��4 ��N���t�D�J��(�j����ғ�齚�r%�d�!��N���t�D�J�"`ܗf�([���r[R,7�?��1��e�����I~�(��@�O��S)�v^�ߖ�F[N��j6oG'���X�Ͳ�a29�*���\�aG*�m��ؓF�A����nW�~�tu="=��R���VnG��(��@ZN�+-��D�J$y��kH�S��4���3�1��l��v�"�x��E7��V?`���l�;���h���s���n���s�*Z�V_�/�&���m2ϨU
�_�n/����c��p>M�v�u,֤��L-�>
G{
�2��Ƹ'��B8﭂��{�*�#}�4lu?�
�2����sŦfwD�.�?��:��#��z�
��kݟ�R�d4H�V�y��N�2��4��x�ˡ�Il�޽��u�������/5{��u#}��דH��8ܮ"����:E�^�Ҕv���PZ{��t� ʗ;����4n�d?�;�^�D�A�D�NYZ��1q<O4�Ҵ�Tu9�qt�ҷ��E�ͯ#U
�����b���0ܺW�\��
z�Ǵ���Fi��5�w�G�q��Z�����}���ϧ��n�{
ٳ�bQ��Uiۼ�-)���۳��s
��?�=�p�:�,Ö��Z8G��I���?�v��?C��U���u�J��P��X�V���zb?M�r�m>����6eҕ��ьƝ��ÉvC�g��.���t�D��V����1�V5Rw�1�v_.�;�����]'d���v�`O�Ҫ�5�1<w�;}���8��(�Q��O3�NY���r�:�z�\p��]Y:�����,�U'�aM���|�q[����J>�H��\c1=���@1>���[B��w�#9~m��C������u���I�8ܮ"����ZE�\G1�m�)�����f�������q
F̟mL�Ob�Aj礭O�:��WKDz���r��z�����gW�I�~e>���H�Ox�|H�?.Z罖��1�1��5aة�M8��~�:�\ƃ����i��Rn8�{R�{���t��yÎ��w��P3�"�]�A���nW�~�tu�#݉�`ROh��X�3>�,�����F���v�HO6RZ�&��"���qQ�>7�ؔ���A�
A�vF��f�^���txO���'u������)����P�j�9�M9�N���
nW�~�tu�#]c"qryF�D���x�w^�ݸj��'}����?����HO�HkJ�O�U��=������
;ݎ�\G�~��.3&}�y�I�7�e�����l_�O���nW�~�tu�#=�D�Ρ��_���c�����j��eN"���'}�6c�H��I�V�c��p����8^��uw$���s7��>_=�i����J�^���F��N���
�X����wjl��1v����.�B�/1��u-T[�~=��R����[��v��p������(nW�~�tu�#��.6��UI�'}�������C�-�e��2�vpŘ��.�UT�������r��9 ����\��&6��D�+��!�>�ԥ��#>Q��q�ųZ*>S��7�
qiW����
cW��6+R҅��l}���yp��^��Ag�27�*���ѥE�KR���6׃�C"}�y��Ȍ//�
���
:�����Z�v0
��pq�]E��%����tŽN�Ep��c�7�k����4ܘLF���l��댧]�\'���X��
��~�:.m���Zx-��x��b���u�����2����8v��uҧ�8��������t�D���~��+�Q
���pʸ]E��%�ճ�ci�ϟI�������t�D����n��%�nO������������pڸ]E��%�Ս��qO�R4&=�]k��������]E��%���?������]E��%�U"�`Ν;������*"�/���������v��HW�t����lp��H�K��D:���@6�]E��%�U"��� ܮ"���*�����
nW�~�t�H�������t�D�J����d��UD�_"]%�������*"�/���������v��HW�t����lp��H�K��D:���@6�]E��%�U"��� ܮ"���*�����
nW�~�t�H�������t�D�J����d��UD�_"]%�������*"�/���������v��HW�t����lp��H�K��D:���@6�]E��%�U"��� ܮ"���*�����
nW�~�t�H�������t�D�J����d��UD�_"]%�������*"�/���������v��HW�t����lp��H�K��D:���@6�]E��%�U"��� ܮ"���*�����
nW�~�t�H�������t�D�J����d��UD�_"]%�������*"�/���������v��HW�t����lp��H�K��D:���@6�]E��%�U"��� ܮ"���*�����
nW�~�t�HI��+����k��KcW׫яn��0��n� [����5}%�gةHq;/9}�^۷G��U�y�Z�>;�~c_
[z./5v�����*"�/���D��UҰ+I+�
ЫYD�9��pף&����ү�h��I�7��h���$㎔5�
նF#���H��~]v4��=���K/�����*"�/����!���I�dOjg�,*9�Ӊ��mFzN��$tS"=x�sg��dԒ�n��w��H��N�5�����*"�/���ǁH?��"}_�����������u�����k:�A�"�h8��^C��������}���ҩe;���e�і����T'�'��T�[����=i�;R��خ
��G��*"�/���G���Wjv�X���H=2H�   �b�%���;8��19w�s,��l|�v�"�x���N7���9`�}i��>�~K�������Pw~q,G�7WS�s��,o���s�GG�������Ė��M�I��aGj{ے�u�0�u4���_��(�� ���FqP�6�Xl��35��vJ�RS��X�bM�:�,P�u��ܦ2�=��cǷ
�_�-��?*��X:U����@�;��t[n�~0e(�fY
�s���D�4��V�迧�U&ү�5(J�3��h �Z1|]�}���%i�ǎڲ����~C��X����
�L"��R�v��HW�)�-�����;�(Ԇ���0+T��2�����84��y;�ޯk픥��X��]��ӈ�h
�i���r4��$�c_�Nzp`��cn�6���f�9p���f1���P���Ұ�枑v�A���5:5)j��L�Y�t��  �F[�5���W�Ѻ)��n�)��h��iW���9�m#'�����gY�4f1��v�ct]5��
�5W,Jq�*��HF�V���Y�Ot����w�c��,��]�y��*��S����6�%�^�į�}b�
���±���/Tv������p��H�K��k��noL�U��]i�;��8V���d�G�݊��U�k��sI�Ƴ�2l�����n+�n%Ti�]����4�u�i���C�����uk����I�.��N?��|P.�D����5��e�m�(`���s*迣�]���.|L�Y�x]��d(��'ϕ��)8��Ά
���t<"��h�k��
�7-҃��M|�6ڶF�H�{:Mr�������4p��H�K��k�i��mC�W��ѐ�`ҥ�(<��s���>���BP-��c�b�:������A=O�}w}I�cүIaz�>m#�9�0�����m�����3��h��Z2t��h��A�a#==�����u����HO��t��K��UD�_"]]�H��M1�t�8J  ˠ]����4R�~ϯ�'��a�&�����nP!��I���L��a��c�7�R�ƛϜ��xО�[�*J���>�5s�;    2���m����磤m��y�&w|�^����~���P"���v��HW�>�5T'�g,G)��2��~�:ܛ�>��hg�m�x�3�
AY��:�����I�����[?�5K�ǞCA�&��̶K[���   �{\�n��X�t]��n�����ݷ�v��ޫ�Afr�c��.)nW�~�tu�#=�D�ͱLE�gܑ��F�;�#�i�s@�&�b��v�{�H��I�V4Ēc��p�H�桱�|q:�q��t9s[i.N�
�2�f�(���z.�������ǹO�X��pXON8�M���Գܺ����G�z��b�D�.T�:��C�\���R�v��HW�9�ø�I�X����B�P����gg���h�N\��+�DWwq��2�ਅ�>�P
��}P ���I�וv�$�yF�U�W�҈�/�/�Jx�{������,����u{��f�Q���(��:w��A���l�Ust�Wwq��R�?8�����MD�1��ܙ{]��v��f$�O@2b']���FkW��6+R�mo���=f�?�,f��Xw�P��2���"�ˌvt[�A�a������e2��R��F�2�� ܮ"����zG��^'�BĮ�uK�8JF���l���G�L\d{bW�1�����߷���&�fy/��ڳS��Zx-��x��b��R��N�a���ȅ�����~��m��ؓ�l#͍�O����6�����h��w��;v��u�u�����_��d��ѷ�G��\*ܮ"����zD��rI�`������`���8�
�����*"�/����H�4qg��~K:ݞ��=i���
�=i����NWz������r����d��UD�_"]��H�4q0Ǹ'�r)vU��=��`��k8�Ҵ!I��Nw���p�nW�~�tu�#�������"nW�~�tu�Ϥ����nW�~�t�H8�s��!"�y�p��H�K��D:���@6�]E��%�U"��� ܮ"���*�����
nW�~�t�H�������t�D�J����d��UD�_"]%�������*"�/���������v��HW�t����lp��H�K��D:���@6�]E��%�U"��� ܮ"���*�����
nW�~�t�H�������t�D�J����d��UD�_"]%�������*"�/���������v��HW�t����lp��H�K��D:���@6�]E��%�U"��� ܮ"���*�����
nW�~�t�H�������t�D�J����d��UD�_"]%�������*"�/���������v��HW�t����lp��H�K��D:���@6�]E��%�U"��� ܮ"���*�����
nW�~�t�H�������t�D����կ~U>�����������Sז��~0X.����I�v��HW�!�-�?�떕�<
u�������*"�/���C�ۙm7��Җ
���pR�]E��%��u�t���sV�r���N
���t�D�zV#�}�{��;w.�{�D:����$nW�~�t�,F���5�\��w�+u�H������*"�/���C�����59   �Eы^$��}�7�����S�������nW�~�tu"�-oy��?�D��_���@������im�����'��UD�_"]]�H��[���Xo��F��꫽��O���u�]��m�����'��UD�_"]]�Hӛ��.����v�ꪫ�կ~��cl���H:�]٭t�_�D_��^�~t���|�]E��%��u��V�%��{ﱵ+�|���<��������
���D:\���v�2�n�����*"�/���C���_�U0^�^��~���>&�����?=��?�c?L�|�-w�I���\�ݾXzR���Z���9���H/�V������v���Z�H_�H��D�q����� �}>��ϖn���X[�zC��-���D��m٫��׮�v�)�^Kj{E�������t�D��    ���\n������zj�����o^x\��#=��R�+�JQ�r;R�ch2��޷��h�oK�Ғ�$�^�D�������l�5�ߩ�k�^F�sgC�ҫ�K!~L�"�x����4�r�a����4�v�M�%�rS���{v&vn~%    [0����l�i�
�R��32�uh�u���mb�[�&);�ے�e�vܫuC8ێ�iJ�������^$g��3fܓ�~!�F[ٯ��U��QU:������9�o�K��a���{+m��Kl���g"�~[���1�>E)�5��{���=nW�~�tu�#�=n7�-��O�"ޝW��F�^�Ҕv�E�PZ{~
��XF��T
L��4�F�=
�-�o�d8J�Y�B[�H��
��)K�?��h �ޞ��D��4�1U]�x���u�K��I���c��c��u���Tj��-F��Y��,J�;���4�� !Cg4���:5)jH΂9]~Y�)T����{
����j7Z�e��Nc�n����lw��[�zV;����̗��H}��6҃g��x��P�k��f�p�(��=i�t�îԊ�/��u���,��|���w^������p)q��H�K����n��Z����<�9
�s�a0i�t=v�k\MI�t���Dw(�}qPk �h�Uf�i�N\&#=�������~"���r������D�nʤ[����h$�S�H��^�f"��N3
��u�U���x�gҫ�l�ʰ�n�e��.=�t�ow�IW����/Rp_�\�������h�A���r:8܆9�o;+ݯˎ�����e�W��3��v��BlzU���ͭ��d��UD�_"]]�HO
���?������M�3�#}.�����t���g�G   &�eO�]v�S   c�����LoQj����^H[��uL%��i�-�)�j�;e�?>+����w9���v�,'X�m�u��(�MD�"��ג��:Ci�m�����x�QD4i��t��Ko���g(�J%z=l���/sC��� Kܮ"����:F�A�~�}P4�F��S����h����hމ1�vM���Ų4R�~ϯO�:�NM�w���S���$����Fg���e)E�gF�Yj;z��t���uN��ID���f��,���^��X%ܮ"����:F�
iI
�e<胢IO4�5����h��?,aѼ�"�a���K��VO[��u�3��x��lH�Bt!�O�Lz0?�'��Y�Yj;z��Y��:'g�r1�~�����"��V���t�D����n'���hғ��0P�6���܇�C�>�HewWCon�r"���'}�P����?�Q#�3&�[�/�I?4:]��T���~}�y�2�ѳ����'X֎>.uh�r�H?|�Xv{��>���J�]E��%��u�t�(���E��T�۸�fqv���I�]�����i��Ă���^�e$�� ��]ܫ�L?8:?�Y���
�>(�
Rm����J�^��
�q�1�`�]���ܗ�t%<���]��a�.u��y�^M�'�'���cG��]�
��y̡�qq91ӫ����X����K���듮T� �PnW��+�t�)����1#���c�HO{}��`�p��H�K�����2���E��\�+�u�5Ђk�wݚK�_�<�v��FX2��g�6�����mLK�m�z���:�����UH���$ʸ[
�A�]Y�t;s��u���x�������F��mg���=�������.�;[��^']�Mx-��;ҕ��e#=����U��*"�/���{����Q>(���~�����v��U��*"�/��nB���P?�E�^�HK{?7&����V���t�D��)�n&C��M�m��"jI�ۓ~�'�Z1�RK��plG��X]ܮ"����&E���q>(�4�H��Q.Ec��1ɵ�`v9DX�#���0nW�~�tu�"ݴ!.���h�lϤ�����v��HW71�OJ"���N���t�D�����7�15�O[[.����I�v��HW�!�;�α/�x\���Q���wEk����p�]E��%��u���h��ٶ!(��-ǖg����8)ܮ"����:D�W���59�|f��l�����'��UD�_"]]�H����ܮ"���*�����
nW�~�t�H�������t�D�J����d��UD�_"]%�������*"�/���������v��HW�t����lp��H�K��D:���@6�]E��%�U"��� ܮ"���*�����
nW�~�t�H�������t�D�J����d��UD�_"]%�������*"�/���������v��HW�t����lp��H�K��D:���@6�]E��%��u�t['DDDē�R�v��HW9�����
nW�~�t�H�������t�D�J����d��UD�_"]%�������*"�/���������v��HW�t����lp��H�K��D:���@6�]E��%�U"��� ܮ"���*�����
nW�~�t�H��8���7����]E��%�U"��`y,'�I��G�ܹsx  �mo��׾���Yܮ"���*����<�w�y�|��_]8���h��^�u
u���t�D�J���,ϗ���,�W�����7���k`���&��UD�_"]%�������Z�p�����\�^گ�Z�kb��:�v��HW�t�����p�B�6��"���������%��������F�
��K/����*����n���_��H�L�t�H��X7��2���E�^گD�fJ��D:���r��n��|��_��͔HW�t����p#=~����J�o�D���D:�������ԩ|}�+$�˥�k�Y~>g�+����*����n�['��O�ŵr�W����>�J�o�D�J���,����yZ~�-?�/��c�裏N�>y���FI{�Y�H�L�t�H��X7���q���j��_|���������t�^m}2�~x����+�I6���/�I>4��w�M��P���˻��>$7��r�ev����k_)���z����^&�?�:yջG�u$���b���˂�t�ríC����H�L�t�H��X7����4��!��}���i�=����%��{����'�m�`
�r�ӾM���륯߿���Ev��.�ۗ�>��ʫ��O���[����������p9^���c�"�ϼJ���y���m����5�M�������}J0�w_��t���W���t�ӐH�L�t�H��X7���''��އ?��0��m�n�M����.��+���ٛ�_�X��o�ϽB�,奝�e<>/��(xO�o~A��y͇    n�F����o�q��'_!��J�����w��׽X#��4yV�_�e=���c�'�9>��������W|�<��O���7�K��;�q/����w�tw˹?�i)�4���&IY���J�o�D�J���,��A�j/��WӍ��>w�G�C���E���W���/����Ά<���"W�f/�Xb=�w[��ˍ��b�^o�ۼ��eO����'�y|i�n�y]���-2�y<��i~D�Pk�z��䱏�F~B�y~c��w�T�����?�
k�/~���/\!W|�K���G���b��)��������F����OE{~b�O���<��m��h����ۺ�|����]}���_|��q����^(��/�������y<�&��6O<��@��b��ҟF�ʳ�����������~����(�k>�D��_��:�������iG�v:�����L^�/�ͭ�IJ�o�D�J���,��=�Щh���4�n'�y����iH����y|��
�(�|����
Z��
�׶оVj�n:?��߽D�}�k�����<}�y����������z{���rC~��
������od6���7[�����������D�fJ��D:���r��n���Zx~.
�n.����G>)���?�gҽ?|���ī��{�\�;�p�����b�ߵ��������x���9�!7}������R�����=z�F�
�u�E���r]��Rx�-r���\�u���������{僯x������Ζ�>���J�o�D�J���,��<���h�9~k�o�����t�5E�b�G�T�kyw���}M���ny�O���/<�>��[�H�������:������k���C���|ɮ���W�
n�+XN�.?"p�#r�}������;�Ӑ���@�3��o�%���?��}X��6y�����>���׾A>����IJ�o�D�J���,���
�'���/L#=���tv���S�ߧ\!�������/��w~��]}�<��,w�:Ə
�G�G�X���?,���
)<����'ɷ��)/��'�?P��#�;�_��<���[��[��.����u٥�'�طn��u? W�+����o�f��9ϔ���>�G�=ߋ�J�o�D�J���,G2�O� �?xC�7|p�NNc�mcѿp��嵕k�i:�O�Z~�o�O<���}<�v6����]����g�}��O�-��Q�:�N����k���~!h� ңu��i? ��}P��J6����?"w���#W��I������
�W�s8)��͔HW�t����p#����+O���-�ޟ��N���N���V����M�����Yػ�1�{��n�}6��-���җ�4�ƴ��!o��ɝƺ"n
w�'��H�L�t�H��X7�-bOK�����}?�ޯm:{�6��v_r�x~i�;l�X�ߞw��N[7wZ�4'-����*����n�[�Z/���~%�7S"]%����Ít���^"}3%�U"��`9��ՓH�L�t�H��X"}�$�7S"]%����#��~�A+����k����o"}�$�U"��`9,���.���?N�_Bm��k��|&xM��͒HW�t�����۵�?��Ogqm�f�m{;X��0�k�.�]E��%�U"��`y��������s��}����\�N����{o��Z|��_�^����*"�/������G�B���Z+�
���׶�����UD�_"]%��������K�:�v��HW�t����lp��H�K��D:���@6�]E��%�U"��� ܮ"���*�����
nW�~�t�H�������t�D�J����d��UD�_"]%�������*"�/���������v��HW�t����lp��H�K��D:���@6�]E��%�U"��� ܮ"���*�����
nW�~�t�H�������t�D�J����d��UD�_"]%�������*"�/���������v��HW�t����lp��H�K���H�Fr�}���L����p|ܮ�β�"�%�U7��9_�p!x�q��ԟ�<ݙ���/G�����머����H����#�C�t��=�P�-�k{�C��B����X?YG�Me}e�e�E�/J����q���cy��G�������?�~�t�BDDDċ���:�z˺��+���Һ�H���`�5���G��=����!"""�Ѵ�J~h4���,:�N���xԶ�����q���{>�y���"?���H��1]�'�(�)�*�x<z��Q7��z�,I�GƑ�K����Q�}��v���[��.�ԧ>%���'��;��`�����   �����������������.�G_�H�����#ݎ�����n�v2�Vq��WDDDD���zɺ���
t���Ytƣ�$�#��=��M�Ϩ۶�1T�=��3
�x�CDDD<�md���uT|=9�=�N��s&#=>��O����N��e�F��dG�f��!"""�g��d�d�d�de=e]e}�<�GzZ��5�t���-��u3Ǻگilg��C�F�^�Ϝ[GYO�g���H%���z��Yu7��hGDDD�y�V���tϞ�~������u;�3m's�gƭ�S2� t�D�G7��b��v8DDDD�7���8'����4��`GDDD��M�ylZ��u��%L�H����~�:�L�.%ҏiڎ��������%�WL"q�$�WL"q�$�WL"q�$�WL"q�$�WL"q�$�WL"q�$�WL"q�$�WL"q�$�WL"q�$�WL"q�$�WL"q�$�WL"q�$�W�Y�������rNF����IEND�B`�
------WebKitFormBoundaryLgBrFdAMLHRuYHlS
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="text-test"

Text test
------WebKitFormBoundaryLgBrFdAMLHRuYHlS--
```

*Please, do not suggest any libraries except for NodeJS' natives.

Comment: There are no built-in modules to do multipart parsing. Why are you against using a third-party module for parsing?

Comment: @mscdex because I want to reinvent the wheel...

Comment: @MichaelSazonov You say splitting by `\r\n\r\n`, does that mean you have loaded all of this data into a string? If so, that is your problem. This is binary data, so trying to load it into a string will corrupt it. You need to process it as a `Buffer`.

Comment: Also, hopefully, since you are reinventing the wheel, it is for the sake of learning. If you are hoping to use this in some real code, I'd encourage you do use existing packages, otherwise you're just asking for a constant stream of issues.

Comment: @loganfsmyth You were right: the `.toString()` on a binary chunk corrupts the data. One solution is to work with the buffer. Another is to use `chunk.toString('binary')`, which actually lets you to operate the chunk as if it was a string with no currently seen data loss.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you say you are `splitting on \r\n\r\n`, I take that to mean that you are converting the data to a string and then parsing it. Using the default `.toString`, this will corrupt the data, because it will try to parse the image's binary data as UTF-8 data.

Personally, I would recommend parsing the data directly from the `Buffer` instance. Another method would be to do `.toString('binary')`, but I would not recommend that (at least in production code) because it will be much slower, and you are potentially increasing the size of the image in-memory greatly. It also means you are moving the image data into `V8`'s memory space, where before it was stored outside. `binary` is also explicitly called out in Node's [`Buffer`](http://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_buffer) docs as deprecated and to be removed in the future.